# Pine script alert shows up without bar closed (real-time) when alertcondition is not met

Tags: pine-script

I'm using this code and the alert is still activated as real-time data.

```
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

bb1 = cross(a1, a2) and rsi < 45 and srsi < 30 and d < 20
bb2 = cross(b1, b2) and rsi < 45 and srsi < 30 and d < 20

alertcondition(condition=bb1 and showsignals ? up : na and barstate.isconfirmed)
alertcondition(condition=bb2 and showsignals ? up : na and barstate.isconfirmed)
```

This code makes false alerts and real alert isn't showed up sometimes. I've set the alert to 'once per bar closed'.

What could've been wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use anything that relies on `high` `low` or `close` without the data being delayed at some point using the history referencing operator, e.g. `close[1]` you are using the live value that updates every tick. This means conditions may evaluate to true, and then false on a tick-by-tick basis. This is called repainting.

Your code is incomplete but the obvious way would be adding `[1]` to bb1 and bb2,

```
alertcondition(condition=bb1[1] and showsignals ? up : na and barstate.isconfirmed)
alertcondition(condition=bb2[1] and showsignals ? up : na and barstate.isconfirmed)
```

This meaning that the condition evaluated to true for the last (confirmed) bar.